# Modify Avg lookupset in SSRS to remove null

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have the follow custom function that I am using in an SSRS report in order to calculate an average value using the LookUpSet function. I have a number of results in the set that are returned that are null. At the moment this function is taking these as 0 and increasing the count. How would I modify this to exclude the 0 values so that it just skips them and keeps the count the same. ie. just excludes them completely from the dataset that is returned?

```
Function AvgLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal

If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If

Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
Dim Avg as Decimal = New Decimal()

suma = 0
ct = 0

For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
ct += 1
Next

Avg = suma / ct

If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return Avg

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest way would be to add a IF statement in your loop. This assumes it is converting the NULLS to 0 and you have no 0 values you want.

```
For Each item As Object In items
     IF Convert.ToDecimal(item) <> 0
        suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
        ct += 1
     ENDIF
Next
```